# NodeJS issue with getting variables at the right time [npm like module]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having the following issue with my nodejs code.

I want to make a simple counter that shows facebook and twitter likes on a webpage. I've found the likes module from npm that does this job easily but I am having issues with getting the values it returns to later populate a webpage.

In the example I have reverted to using a global scope to try and fix my issue.

I kind of understand what is going on with the Async calls but don't know how to solve it.

I've chosen NodeJS to do this project so I can get more familiar with the technology. The [likes module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/likes) can be found via the link.

The desired outcome is that I end up with two variables one for facebook and one for twitter that I can later use to populate a counter on a webpage.

If any pointers or suggestions that could be given that would be great. I understand this is a very noob/fundamental question but I can't seem to figure whats wrong.

```js
var likes = require('likes')

global.twitterFollowers = 0
global.facebookLikes = 0

function getLikes()
{

    likes.facebook('me' , function (err , count)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        }
        
        global.facebookLikes = count
        console.log("FACEBOOK: " , global.facebookLikes)
        
    })
    
    likes.twitter('me' , function (err , count)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.error(err)
            process.exit(1)
        }

        global.twitterFollowers = count
        console.log("TWITTER: " , global.twitterFollowers)
        
        
        
        
    })
}

getLikes()

console.log('I have ' , global.facebookLikes , ' likes on Facebook!')
console.log('I have ' , global.twitterFollowers , ' followers on Twitter!')
```

This is what is returned on the command line, I would of expected the zero values to be populated with the 'FACEBOOK:' values.

```
I have  0  likes on Facebook!
I have  0  followers on Twitter!
TWITTER:  1887
FACEBOOK:  242
```

Comment: You should use promises and `Promise.all()` instead of simply callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Promises, it will make the things more readable.

I'm goind to mock the facebook and twitter requests for example purpose, with those functions :

```
function getFacebooksExample(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, 242);
  }, 2000)
}

function getTwitterExample(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, 1887);
  }, 3000)
}
```

Basically, the callback of each function will be the same as the `likes` module, so you can use `util.promisify`. `util.promisify` is provided by Node for the purpose of making a function that uses a callback as parameter return a promise instead.

The Facebook "request" will take 2 seconds, and the Twitter request 3 seconds for this example.

Now, you can use `Promise.all()` to run all promises *concurrently*, and return when they all resolved, so you don't have to wait for the first one to end before starting the second.

```
const util = require('util');

async function getikes() {
  return await Promise.all([
    util.promisify(getFacebooksExample)(),
    util.promisify(getTwitterExample)()
  ])
}

function getFacebooksExample(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, 242);
  }, 2000)
}

function getTwitterExample(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, 1887);
  }, 3000)
}

getikes().then(console.log)
```

**Edit :** If you cannot use `util.promisify`, you can still return Promises like this :

```js
async function getikes() {
  return await Promise.all([
    getFacebooksExample(),
    getTwitterExample()
  ])
}

function getFacebooksExample(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(242);
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function getTwitterExample(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1887);
    }, 3000)
  })
}

getikes().then(console.log)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have copied your alterations and it works. From the other comments I can see that I've got quite a bit to learn about the language

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is Asynchronous language which use event loop. In your code these lines are executing before the function `getLikes()` finishes.

```
console.log('I have ' , global.facebookLikes , ' likes on Facebook!')
console.log('I have ' , global.twitterFollowers , ' followers on Twitter!')
```

You can simply use Async/Await syntax and can await on `await getLikes()` call.
Although your global variables have set the values after the console logs, and you can consume the values later. But if you do not use callback, promises or async/await you will not know when `getLikes()` finish execution. I would like to suggest you to have watch a few tutorials about callbacks, promises and async/await. It will help you to survive and fight in the JS world.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have realised that I've got a lot more to learn

Answer (score 0):

Your code works asynchronously, I'd recommend you to promisify callback-based methods and use async/await to make it work as synchronous code.
See the following code for example. Don't forget to install **bluebird** package first.

Also, I'd recommend you to **get rid of global variables** and simply **return them from the getLikes** function.

```
const likes = require('likes')
const Promise = require('bluebird');

async function getLikes() {
    try {
        const facebookLikesPromise = Promise.promisify(likes.facebook)('me');
        const twitterFollowersPromise = Promise.promisify(likes.twitter)('me');
        const [facebookLikes, twitterFollowers] = await Promise.all([facebookLikesPromise, twitterFollowersPromise]);
        console.log("FACEBOOK: ", facebookLikes)
        console.log("TWITTER: ", twitterFollowers)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }

    return { facebookLikes, twitterFollowers };
}

getLikes()
    .then(({ facebookLikes, twitterFollowers }) => {
        console.log('I have ', facebookLikes, ' likes on Facebook!')
        console.log('I have ', twitterFollowers, ' followers on Twitter!')
    })
```

PS. If you use Node 8.0.0+ then you can use  **util.promisify** instead of **bluebird promisify**

Comment: no need for `bluebird` for promises, because `promises` are natively supported by all big browser vendors (not sure about IE(9) though)

Comment: You should run the 2 requests at the same time, no need to wait for one before starting the other.

Comment: @Seblor Agree. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have realised that I've got a lot more to learn